# New case email alert for related account owner

Tags: salesforce, case, owner, email-notifications

Desired scenario:

*When a new case is received, and meets certain criteria, an email is sent to the owner of the account that the case relates to.*

I could create a workflow and email alert for each user who is able to own accounts, but it seems inefficient and overly complex to have several workflows running to evaluate each new case that meets the criteria.

I have no experience with APEX code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a case email alert for recipient type of "Account Owner"